# Regex to remove to t/a-Z/

Tags: java, regex

What is a regex to remove the letter `t` followed a forward slash followed by any letter any case followed by forward slash. I tried a few regex but nothing came close

eg

> http//mysite.com/home/t/images/folder1
>
> to
>
> http//mysite.com/home/folder1

Comment: 'I tried a few regex but nothing came close'. Could we see the one which appeared the closest to you?

Comment: regex doesn't change strings.  it only finds matches

Comment: To find the string you're describing, use `t/[a-zA-Z]/`. You may need to escape the slashes to be `t\/[a-zA-Z]\/` or even `t\\/[a-zA-Z]\\/` depending on your use context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.replaceAll("t/[a-zA-Z]*/", "")
```

This code prints required string "http//mysite.com/home/folder1":

```
String s = "http//mysite.com/home/t/images/folder1";
s = s.replaceAll("t/[a-zA-Z]*/", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

Regexp contains [a-zA-Z] construct - a through z, or A through Z, inclusive (range).

'*' is a quantifier - zero or more times.
 If this part is never empty it could be substituted with '+' - one or more times.

[Description of regex character classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)
[Description of quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Comment: You _could_ elaborate more :)

Comment: I wrote this code in main function: String s = "http//mysite.com/home/t/images/folder1";
s = s.replaceAll("t/[a-zA-Z]*/", "");
System.out.println(s);

Comment: It prints 'http//mysite.com/home/folder1' :)

Comment: That's my first answer. I decided that in less amount of characters I would make less amount of mistakes :)

Comment: yes - but it was flagged as "not an answer", therefore I was looking at it. I tagged it with false flags, eg as a "good answer", but you could explain the parts of your regex to make it more useful for future visitors. Just hit Edit and explain why you think this is an answer (I do not doubt you have given a good answer)

Answer (score 1):

The text of your question doesn't quite line up with your example - your question says that there must be t, then /, then a letter, then / again; but your example shows multiple letters between the slashes.

Assuming that multiple letters are what you're after, you could use `"t/[a-zA-Z]+/"` - Note that the `+` sign is regular-expression-speak for "one or more".